# Pointer set in function returning as correct type

Tags: c

Let say I have a function where two of the parameters are global arrays. Code would look something like this:

```
/*global variable*/
int    Input_Messages          [Num_Messages ][Num_Elements];

static void Set_Conditions()
{
     PACK(250.0, (unsigned short*)&Input_Messages[0][15], (unsigned short*)&Input_Messages[0][16], 18, 19, -1, 1.0);
}

void PACK(float value, unsigned short *Hi, unsigned short *Lo, long bit, long word, long lsb, float scale)
{
     unsigned long Value32;
     .
     .
     .
     /*last bit of code where *Hi and *Lo are set*/
     *Lo = (unsigned short)(Value32);
     *Hi = ((unsigned short)(((Value32) >> 16) & 0xFFFF));
}
```

The problem I am facing is as follows:

After `PACK()` is completed, it returns the values of `*Lo` and `*Hi` to the `Input_Messages[0][15]` and `[0][16]` respectively. The issue I am having on a big endian machine is that after all this is complete, if you look at those values for Input_Messages, they have been converted to a long, whereas I need a short. An example is if at the end of `PACK()`, `*Lo` is set to `62 (003E)`, when it returns back into `Set_Conditions()`, if you look at the `Input_Messages[0][16]`, instead of `62`, it would be `4063232 (003E0000)`.

I managed to fix this by changing the `global Input_Messages[][]` from `int`, to `unsigned short`, but in doing that, a lot of other changes are needed in function calls, etc. I guess I am trying to see if there is an easier way to set it so it returns as a short, and stays a short. Some sort of casting or something.

Let me know if more explanation is needed. I tried to explain it best as I could, and post relevant code, but I will answer any questions I can.

Comment: This is not clear.  If you want `short`s, then why have you defined `Input_Messages` as `int`?

Comment: Input_Messages was originally implemented as an int so as to handle code in other places. It can be changed to a short, but that requires more code to be updated to accommodate that change. I guess I was just seeing if there was anything I could do with the casting, or anything else to solve the problem without that change.

Comment: What happens on a machine where `sizeof(long)>2*sizeof(short)`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess i'm not understand your question..

Comment: If `sizeof(long)==8` and `sizeof(short)==2` then `Lo` and `Hi` aren't meaningful anymore. It's hard to tell from here, but the code design seems a little fragile to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this case, sizeof(long) == 4 bytes and sizeof(short) == 2 bytes.

Comment: Why not just declare `Lo` and `Hi` as `int*` in the parameter list of `PACK`?

Comment: @DanielFischer I need them to be short, as they are showing the low 2 bytes, and the high 2 bytes of Value32. I just need it to remain a short when Pack() exits and Lo and Hi point back to Input_Messages

Comment: I don't understand. You want to set `Input_Messages[0][15]` to the value of the low 2 bytes of `Value32`, and `Input_Messages[0][16]` to the high 2 bytes, right? That's exactly what happens if you declare the `Lo` and `Hi` parameters of `Pack()` as `int*` and omit the cast in the call, leaving everything else unchanged. If you set `*Lo` and `*Hi` as `int`s, the endianness of the machine is irrelevant, the values are set with the same endianness as they are read.

Comment: @DanielFischer So you are saying that *Hi and *Lo should be set as int* s, and to do away with the casting in the call to Pack() and the casting where *Hi and *Lo are set within Pack() ?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your exact requirements are, but that seems to be the correct way.